# RandomAccessFile and read/write start-finish position

Tags: java

I've searched this a lot but still can't find... So I hope you can help me to understand :)

The question is...

I have big file A.dat and I want

- A) Read it with RandomAccessFile (to
  avoid OutOfMemory error)
- B) Read it by pieces of 4Mb (buffer)
- C) Write each this 4Mb piece to file
  B.dat
- D) So to make file B.dat as a copy of
  file A.dat

But I have a problem... If I have a file which length cannot be devided by 4Mb the data get lost and file become corrupted :(

For example...
I have media file. Its length is 15.8Mb so I can get only 15.8Mb/4Mb=3 whole pieces. Then I can write only those 3 bytes pieces and the rest get lost :( 
Or the problem is if file is smaller than buffer size (4Mb)...

I think it shouldn't be a hard task but I couldn't see any standart tutorial which shows how to solve such kind of things...

I dearly hope you can help me with this question.

Comment: @userNNNN "I dearly hope you can help me with this question."  Perhaps that will go better when you ask a question.

Comment: i am not sure this is what you want, but if you want to copy files, use instead [java NIO](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17036.html). it is safer and a lot faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `RandomAccessFile` does not seem useful in this case.  Using traditional stream-based I/O is best and certainly won't lead to out of memory errors unless you're doing it wrong.  Here's really all the code you need (untested):

```
InputStream in = null;
OutputStream out = null;
try {
    in = new FileInputStream("a.dat");
    out = new FileInputStream("b.dat");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4*1024*1042]; //4 MiB
    for ( int len = 0; (len = in.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
       out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
} finally {
    if ( in != null )
       try { in.close() } catch (IOException ignore) {}
    if ( out != null )
       try { out.close() } catch (IOException ignore) {}
}
```

If you really need a `RandomAccessFile` for some reason you can't tell us, the method is essentially the same.  Find out how much data you actually read into your buffer using the result from `RandomAccessFile.read(byte[], int, int)` and use that number to limit how much you write back to the output file.

### Edit

The above warrants some explanation.  Here are the key parts:

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4*1024*1042]; //4 MiB
```

This initializes a byte array of 4 binary megabytes which will hold one chunk of the file at a time.

```
    for ( int len = 0;
```

In a for loop, we start by declaring a value `len` that will record how many bytes we have read in.

```
(len = in.read(buffer)) != -1;
```

Then we invoke `read` on the `InputStream`.  This will read bytes into the byte array until either the buffer is full, or there is no more data left to read (the end of file is reached).  The number of bytes actually read is returned by this method and assigned to `len`.  If that value is -1, that means the stream is closed so we exit the loop.

```
) {
   out.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
```

Then, for each chunk that we have read, we write it to the output stream.  `buffer` indicates we want to write from our byte array, the `0` indicates we want to start at the beginning of the array, and the `len` says how many bytes to write.  Remember, if our buffer wasn't filled then `len` will have been set accordingly and only part of the array will be written.

I gave you the idiomatic version which can be more difficult to follow.  Here's a more straightforward way of doing the same thing:

```
int numberOfBytesRead;
while ( true ) {
   numberOfBytesRead = in.read(buffer); //read bytes into buffer
if ( numberOfBytesRead == -1 ) break; //end of stream
   out.write(buffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead); //write the same # of bytes we read
}
```

### See

- [InputStream.read(byte[])](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29)
- [OutputStream.write(byte[], int, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: Thank you for such a quick comment.

Comment: So you mean if I just use FileInputStream with buffer reading I shouldn't get OutOfMemory error? Can I read Gb files with this code?

Comment: Emm but the code like ...

int len = 0; (len = in.read(buffer)) != -1;

What if the buffer length is bigger than the last iteration reading result?

Comment: @user:  Yes, you won't run into an `OOME` because you are only keeping a small fragment of the file in memory at any given time.  The `read()` method returns how many bytes were read into the byte buffer.  By using that information when you `write()` the bytes back, you can handle an odd sized block at the end.  The buffer will be partially empty but you won't write that part.

Comment: @user: I added some explanation to my answer.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, Mark :)

Thank you for code and such a detailed description.

But without using buffer I could only get the OutOfMemory Error in read(in) method... 

But what about RandomAccessFile? Is it useful just to read some specified file pieces or it can be useful for more tasks?

Comment: @user: RandomAccessFile is particularly useful if you want to efficiently "jump" to some location in a file and read/write from there.  With a stream, you would have to read up to that point and ignore what you've read, which is inefficient.  If you're not planning on jumping to a point in a file, it's not of much use.

Comment: I could hear the RandomAccessFile can be useful for client/server files sending? Is it true or FileOutputStream is OK as for this thing?

Comment: @user:  For sending over an network I don't see how RAF could possibly help, since network communication is intrinsically stream-based.  You would probably have a SocketInputStream and SocketOutputStream instead of FileInputStream and FileOutputStream.

Comment: Emm... It was about Applet... so Socket is quite unusual in this case I guess? But the RAF was advised as a suitable thing for this applet/servlet communication... I don't know exactly but it was someplace google B)

Anyway thank you for helping me to understand how to output large files :)

Andrew